# How to scrape table with no id/class to dataframe with Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am trying to scrape a table on a website that has no id/class, therefore making it difficult to target the exact table I want.

webpage: https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/

I am trying to scrape the table under Possible Bogus Routes and put them into a `dataframe`, but unsure how to. So far, I am able to print all table rows, but not this specific one

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

bogus = soup.find_all("tr")
for data in bogus:
    print(data.text)
```

The end result would be like this:

```
[
   {prefix: '23.139.232.0/24', origin: 'AS211619', description: 'MAXKO, HR', unallocated: '23.139.225.0 - 23.139.247.255'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect a [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), why not simply use [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)?

```
df = pd.read_html("https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/")[13] # <-- the 14th table
```

Output :

```
print(df)

               Prefix Origin AS            AS Description         Unallocated block
0     23.139.232.0/24  AS211619                 MAXKO, HR  23.139.225.0 - 23.139...
1     23.140.216.0/24   AS27176             DATAWAGON, US  23.140.209.0 - 23.140...
2       23.141.0.0/24  AS395350         -Reserved AS-, ZZ  23.140.250.0 - 23.141...
..                ...       ...                       ...                       ...
634  217.197.100.0/24   AS41720  Contact: info@navigab...  217.197.96.0 - 217.19...
635  217.197.103.0/24  AS206068            HOSTING-UP, MD  217.197.96.0 - 217.19...
636  217.197.106.0/24  AS204471             KARSOLINK, IT  217.197.96.0 - 217.19...

[637 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you don't want to use `pandas`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data, names = [], ('prefix', 'origin', 'description', 'unallocated')
for row in soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("Possible Bogus Routes") + * tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    data.append(
        dict(zip(names, tds))
    )

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
    ...

    {
        "prefix": "217.197.100.0/24",
        "origin": "AS41720",
        "description": "Contact: info@navigabene.it, IT",
        "unallocated": "217.197.96.0 - 217.197.111.255"
    },
    {
        "prefix": "217.197.103.0/24",
        "origin": "AS206068",
        "description": "HOSTING-UP, MD",
        "unallocated": "217.197.96.0 - 217.197.111.255"
    },
    {
        "prefix": "217.197.106.0/24",
        "origin": "AS204471",
        "description": "KARSOLINK, IT",
        "unallocated": "217.197.96.0 - 217.197.111.255"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

While using [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) you could use the `match` parameter to pick your table by text matching:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html("https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/", match='Origin AS')[0]
```

|  | Prefix | Origin AS | AS Description | Unallocated block |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23.139.232.0/24 | AS211619 | MAXKO, HR | 23.139.225.0 - 23.139.247.255 |
| 1 | 23.140.216.0/24 | AS27176 | DATAWAGON, US | 23.140.209.0 - 23.140.223.255 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 635 | 217.197.103.0/24 | AS206068 | HOSTING-UP, MD | 217.197.96.0 - 217.197.111.255 |
| 636 | 217.197.106.0/24 | AS204471 | KARSOLINK, IT | 217.197.96.0 - 217.197.111.255 |